# Update view from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i want to retrieve data from mysql database in android and show in textview

it shows an error

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.learnersarena.practicemysql, PID: 23452
>                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
>                         at com.example.learnersarena.practicemysql.BackgroundAsyncTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundAsyncTask.java:110)
>                         at com.example.learnersarena.practicemysql.BackgroundAsyncTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundAsyncTask.java:26)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)

this is the background asynctask code

```
public class BackgroundAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
Context ctx;
TextView tv;

BackgroundAsyncTask(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
}
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String insert_url="http://192.168.10.3:81/android_exam_practice/insert.php";
    String select_url="http://192.168.10.3:81/android_exam_practice/select.php";
    String method=params[0];
    if(method.equals("insert"))
    {
        String name=params[1];
        String email=params[2];
        try {
            URL url=new URL(insert_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream=httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
            String data= URLEncoder.encode("name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            inputStream.close();
            return "data inserted ";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if(method.equals("select"))
    {
 //   String Name=params[1];
   // String Email=params[2];
        try {
            URL url=new URL(select_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("post");
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            //OutputStream outputStream=httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            //BufferedWriter bufferedWriter=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
            //String data =URLEncoder.encode("");
            InputStream inputStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String response ="";
            String line ="";
            while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
            {
                response+=line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
   // Toast.makeText(ctx, aVoid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    tv.setText(aVoid);
}
```

}

Comment: you never initialize your TextView so your tv variable is always null , and when you want to setText on that TextView you get this, initiate it somewhere in your code

Comment: so how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: you have to have a xml layout file and define your TextView in that file, and initiate your textview throw id which your TextView have inside layout file, or you can create dynamic TextView, and bind it to your UI programmatically

Comment: i have 3 java classes 2 have xml file and one is not BackgroundAsyncTask is a java file no xml file

Answer (score 1):

**Your solution is here.**

In your `onPostExecute()` method initialize the `textview`

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
   // Toast.makeText(ctx, aVoid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    tv = findViewById(R.id.textView); 
    tv.setText(aVoid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**BackgroundAsyncTask** in your application is a thread other than UI thread so if you need to update any view you can create an *public* and *static* method in your Activity/Fragment and call this method from using  **runOnUiThread()** method as:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         // call your method here.
    }
});
```

**OR**

make use of Handler's
[check this to know more about Handler's](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui)

Answer (score 0):

Change the constructor of `BackgroundAsyncTask` from:

```
BackgroundAsyncTask(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
}
```

to

```
BackgroundAsyncTask(Context ctx, TextView tv) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.tv = tv;
}
```

So when you initialize the `BackgroundAsyncTask` in your activity, instead of:

```
new BackgroundAsyncTask(this)
```

write

```
new BackgroundAsyncTask(this, tv)
```

where `tv` is your activity's `TextView` that you want to update.